# Python Turtle diagonal lines wrong length?

Tags: python, geometry, turtle-graphics

When trying to paint a square with a diagonal line in it, the line is not rendered at the correct length.
Code:

```
import turtle
i = 0
while i < 4:
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
turtle.left(135)
turtle.forward(100)
```

The loop should (and does) paint a perfect square.
The following two lines should turn the turtle in the right direction for a diagonal line (and it does so).

My geometrical knowledge tells me that in a square the length of diagonals is equal to the length of the sides.

This example does not accomplish this. The diagonal stops at about 2/3 of its way. It works if I send the turtle forward for 145 steps - but that's total nonsense to me. I want to use this in a school lesson for pupils and I can't understand the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: "the length of diagonals is equal to the length of the sides" -- Incorrect. The length of the diagonal is `sqrt(2)*side`

Comment: Oh lord thank you. Got tricked by my old mind.

Comment: Good ol' Pythagorean theorem at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why, but on my computer turning by 135 didn't put the line within the square.

Here is what I did

```
import turtle
from math import sqrt

side = 100
turn_angle = 90

for i in range(4):
    turtle.forward(side)
    turtle.left(turn_angle)
turtle.left(0.5*turn_angle)
turtle.forward(side*sqrt(2))

turtle.mainloop()
```

Makes this

[image: turtle square with line]